# Increase loading and concurrent users on WCF Service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-7

I have an internal website which calls multiple calls to the WCF service which is hosted in IIS 7 Windows 2008 R2 server.

During the heavy loading period when it is being used by 50-75 users, it returns FaultException in WCF calls.  I highly doubt that it is because of the user loading because we are using the same website for almost a year and we haven't got the same error before.  Some of the calls might take 2 or 3 sec to execute.

So, I added the following lines in web.config file in the Host Service.  Do I need to add anything anywhere?  Do I need to do anything in the client website too?  Thanks.

```
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
    <serviceThrottling 
    maxConcurrentCalls="100" 
    maxConcurrentSessions="100" 
    maxConcurrentInstances="100"
      />

</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Comment: I think the limit is 10.

Answer (score 0):

Before changing configurations arbitrarly I would look for the reason of why it fails.

Since your calls take 2/3s to return we can safely assume that you achieve more than 10 instances created (10 is the default) at a given time. When that happens the calls queue up and if your load don't drop so every call can be replied to you are going to have problems.

You can do that diagnose by looking at [performance counters that WCF provides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098.aspx), specially at Instance counters related to ServiceModelService 4.0.0.0.

If that is the problem (looks like it could be) then you can take action and increase the number of instances. However, the ultimate fix should be decrease response times because otherwise you will just be postponing the problems that comes with scaling.